# How to execute shell command or call URL on new gitlab issue?

Tags: git, gitlab

I want to execute a shell command or call a URL when a user creates a new issue. The reason behind this is to synchronize our Gitlab issues with our CalDav calendar infrastructure. We are using Gitlab community.

Answer (score 1):

That's mostly what gitlab [webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#webhooks) are for I think.

For your case that would be an [issue event](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html#issues-events) and you'll have to create something to parse the posted json and do whatever is needed on your CalDav infra to match your needs.